# put search terms on friendly url

Tags: javascript, forms, search, friendly-url

I have used a jQuery plugin to slug strings used in a search form. So I send to backend a friendly url with the slug terms used in the search by the user.

The problem is when the backend can´t find the term on database, and I need to show a message to say that the original word was not found. The original word was lost when converting to slug.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Any tip?

Sorry by the english, I´m not fluent

Answer (score 0):

You can do POST request and put in the attribute action of the form the friendly url with the slug terms.

$_POST will have the original search term typed by the user